# Konjunktiv I bei Bericht eigener Gedanken

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech

Wenn man über die eigenen Gedanken berichtet, ist die Konjunktiv I zu verwenden? Ich bin beispielsweise auf folgendes in einem Buch gestoßen:

> "Ja", sagte Frodo, "aber ich dachte, mein Fortgang sei ein Geheimnis..."

Und noch eine kleine Frage dazu: Gilt der Bericht eigener Gedanken als indirekte Rede?

Comment: Meiner Meinungnach handelt es sich um einen [Irrealis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis). Frodo erkennt ja gerade, dass er auf dem Holzweg war, also ist der Indikativ nicht mehr die passende Form. Mit indirekter Rede hat das nichts zu tun.

Comment: @guidot Wäre jedoch nicht Konjunktiv II besser dazu passend als Konjunktiv I, wenn es sich dabei um einen Irrealis handelte?

Comment: Ich glaube aber, dass der Konjunktiv I hier falsch verwendet worden ist und es sollte der Konjunktiv II sein. "aber ich dachte, mein Fortgang wäre ein Geheimnis..." wäre (!) richtig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eine solche Konstruktion wird als *(indirekte) Gedankenrede* bezeichnet. Sie wird wie indirekte Rede konstruiert, steht aber mit einem "verbum credendi" (dachte, meinte, empfand, ...) ist.

Wie bei der Redewiedergabe *kann* eine Gedankenrede mit einem Konjunktiv I konstruiert werden. Das zitierte Beispiel ist deshalb korrekt! Andere Konstruktionen sind natürlich auch möglich, z.B.: »Ich dachte: Mein Fortgang ist doch ein Geheimnis!« (zitierte Gedankenrede).

Im Präsens sollte bei der Gedankenrede allerdings kein Konjunktiv I stehen – zumindest klingt »Ich denke, das sei ein Geheimnis« für mich, als ob der Sprecher den Gedanken zugleich bekräftigt und infrage stellt. Man könnte stattdessen »Ich denke, das ist ein Geheimnis« oder »Ich denke, dass das ein Geheimnis ist« sagen.

Ein Konjunktiv II, wie in den Kommentaren angesprochen, ist auch möglich. Damit würde Frodo eine höhere Distanz zu seinen früheren Gedanken zum Ausdruck bringen. Ein Konjunktiv II würde meinem Empfinden nach außerdem wie eine Rückfrage klingen: »Ich dachte, mein Fortgang wäre ein Geheimnis" könnte z.B. mit einer Bekräftigung beantwortet werden, dass Frodos Fortgang in Wahrheit kein Geheimnis ist.

Siehe auch:

- http://www.li-go.de/prosa/prosa/indirektegedankenrede.html
- Lahn/Meister, *Einführung in die Erzähltextanalyse* (Buchvorschau bei Google Books)